# Haproxy httpchk with json

Tags: haproxy, json

I need to check backend with POST JSON but cannot find a way to do this. Below is the curl POST that works. How do I do with in HAPROXY httpchk

```
 curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '["za.co.calculator",{"grossMonthlyIncome":["java.math.BigDecimal",100000.00],"loanTermYears":20,"interestRate":["java.math.BigDecimal",10.25]}]' https://servername/calculator/api/calculator/calculateMaximumLoanAmount
```

My HaProxy config is:

```
option httpchk POST /calculator-service-2.0/api/calculator/calculateMaximumLoanAmount HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 174\r\n\r\n{"za.co.fnb.soa.calculator.dto.S_MaxBondInputInfo",{"grossMonthlyIncome":["java.math.BigDecimal",100000.00],"loanTermYears":20,"interestRate":["java.math.BigDecimal",10.25]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would be nice if you would have shown what you've tried **before** you came here asking for help, but anyway..I didn't test the following, but this might serve you as a starting point:

```
option httpchk POST /calculator/api/calculator/calculateMaximumLoanAmount HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type:\ application/json\r\nContent-Length:\ 144\r\n\r\n["za.co.calculator",{"grossMonthlyIncome":["java.math.BigDecimal",100000.00],"loanTermYears":20,"interestRate":["java.math.BigDecimal",10.25]}]
```

Note: You might need to fix the `Content-Lengtt` param and escaping of special chars, newlines, etc.

Comment: You beat me by 40 seconds. I think the content-length needs to be 144 for this request (that's the length of the original request anyway)

Comment: @MarkHenderson ;) Thanks, I'll incorporate your fix.

Comment: I have added my config above. The reason I had 174 was when I ran curl with -v it shows at content lenght 174

Comment: @gf_  I tried you config, which doesnt work.

Comment: @isa "Doesn't work" isn't really helpful. Please elaborate, show your full config, omit sensitive details if needed, and / or logs showing the failing health check.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I finally have it working. I needed to add the `Host:\ haproxyservices`

```
option httpchk POST /calculator/api/calculator/calculateMaximumLoanAmount HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ haproxyservices\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length:\ 174\r\n\r\n{"za.co.calculator",{"grossMonthlyIncome":["java.math.BigDecimal",100000.00],"loanTermYears":20,"interestRate":["java.math.BigDecimal",10.25]}}
```

Thanks for the assistance.